# Laravel Multiple Filter return True/False

Tags: url, laravel, filter, return

```
Route::filter('age', function($route, $request, $value){
   return ($value>=40);
});
Route::filter('auth', function(){
    return (Input::get('auth')=='yes');
});
Route::get('barx', array('before' => 'age:40|auth', function(){
        return 'Hello World';
}));
```

WHAT URL SHOULD I CALL TO REACH TO 'Hello World'
I AM TRYING `http://laravel/barx?auth=yes` BUT IT'S NOT WORKING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figure it out myself.

```
/*
filter accept only two arguments, second is closure.
filter always send a string/Redirect as a response. Can't be a boolean
If any of filter return a string then it will be consider an exit.
::EXAMPLE BELOW::
*/
Route::filter('old', function(){if(Input::get('age')>=50)return "Old";});
Route::filter('adult', function($route, $request, $value){if($value>=18)return "adult"; });
Route::get('barx', array('before' => 'old|adult:18', function(){return 'You are a child';}));
```

Now try URL `http://laravel/barx?age=12`
and by change value of adult in code `adult:18` currently in code.
If you put `adult below 18` and `age below 50` then it will say 'You are a child'